# Create a new matrix with values that appear in two separate matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

I am new to Matlab and thus this could be a very trivial question and I appreciate those who take the time to help. I have a 618x2 matrix that has values in the first column and then the index of the value (circles on an image for this case). For example

46.9810, 1

0, 2

0, 3

0, 4

43.1429, 5

0, 6

0, 7...

This matrix is called 'Test2'

I have another matrix that is a 1x58 matrix (called overlapindex) The values in this matrix correspond to the index in the 'Test2' matrix
for example:
1, 3, 5, 7, 35, 37, 44, 49,....

I need a new matrix (let's call it NEW) that checks if the value in overlapindex has a nonzero correlating value in the 'Test2' matrix. For example, this NEW matrix would include [43.1429, 5] because the index is in both 'Test2' and also in 'overlapindex' and the corresponding value in 'Test2' is nonzero.

so essentially this 'NEW' matrix would look like...

46.9810, 1

43.1429, 5

and so on until all the indexes are checked and the 'NEW' matrix is made.

I just need to make sure that the index in 'overlapindex' corresponds to an actual non zero value in the 'Test2' matrix.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want the rows of the first matrix that have a non-zero first column and their second column appears in `Test2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved using [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) in Matlab:

```
NEW = Test2(overlapindex(Test2(overlapindex, 1) ~= 0), :)
```

**Explanation**

`Test2(overlapindex, 1)`: rows which should be checked ([accessing Nonconsecutive Elements](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85553))
`Test2(overlapindex, 1) ~= 0`: checks for every requested row if the condition is true
`overlapindex(Test2(overlapindex, 1) ~= 0)`: indexes of the matched rows ([logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1))

Note that this solution only works if `overlapindex` only contains existing indexes of `Test2`, but the solution could be easily extended to skip non-existing indexes.